# Class with a list of materials: best practice

Tags: oop, abap

I've created the custom class ZMaterial that can be instantiated passing an ID to the constructor which sets the properties for a single material using SELECTs and BAPIs. This class is basically used to READ and UPDATE a single material.

Now I need to create a service to return a list of materials. I already have the procedural code for it in a static method (for now actually a function module), but I would like to keep using a full OOP approach and instantiate a list of my custom material object. The first approach I found is to enhance the static method to instantiate a list of my single material object after the selects are executed and I have the data in internal tables, but it does not seem the most OOP.

The second option in my mind is to create a new class ZMaterialList with one property being a list of objects ZMaterial and then a constructor with the necessary input parameters for the database select. The problem I see with this option is that I create a full class just for the constructor.

What do you think is the best way to proceed?

Comment: Keep things simple (KISS). You only need to return a list of materials. So you don't need to instantiate materials now. This is the TDD approach (YAGNI). (sorry for the acronyms)

Comment: How much does `ZMaterial` do upon construction? Does it only store the material's ID? Or does it already perform SELECTs to retrieve relevant data and configuration?

Comment: But then I don't need to create objects never at first sight... Every independent requirement I get is individually very simple and I could do the full project with RFCs or REST services without much effort just calling the required BAPIs, but all together the things get more complicated and in this project I wanted to try to build a full OOP approach with automated unit tests, something I've never done before. @Florian: The constructor is actually checking if the material is assigned to a particular classification class since it's a "ZXCLASSMaterial", it also reads MARA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate class to produce the list of materials. The *single responsibility principle* says each class should do exactly one thing. In all but the most simple cases, *using* a thing is a different responsibility than *producing* it.

Don’t make a ZMaterialList class. A list’s focus would be managing the list items, i.e. adding, removing, iterating, sorting etc. But you should be fine with a regular STANDARD TABLE OF REF TO ZMaterial.

Make a ZMaterialReader, -Repository, -Query or -Factory class or the like, depending on the precise way you want to produce the ZMaterials. Readers read by keys, repositories read and write, queries use varying sets of selection criteria, factories instantiate with possibly different sets of inputs.

You can well let that class use the original FUNCTION underneath. It’s good style to exploit what’s already there. Just make sure you trust that code, put it in a test harness, and keep it afar from the rest of your oo code.

Extract all public interaction of ZMaterial to an interface and use only that interface. That allows you to offer alternative implementations of ZMaterial, ones that differ in the way they are produced or how they store their data.

Split single production from mass production. Reading MARA to retrieve a single material is okay. But you don’t want thousands of ZMaterials reading MARA individually - that wrecks performance.

Now you’ve got the interface, you could offer a second implementation of ZMaterial whose constructor receives all relevant data and relies on it already having been validated to avoid additional SELECTs.

You could also offer an implementation that doesn’t store its data at all but only stores pointers to rows in internal tables somewhere else. See the *flyweight* pattern for ideas.

If you expect mass updates on the materials, such as “reclassify all of these as B”, consider extracting these list-oriented operations to separate classes as well.

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you! I'm not able to understand and implement all your suggestions, but I'll do my best. For my specific scenario I think I need ZMaterialReader Query class since I don't expect massive updates, only queries to get specific sets of materials. I will try to figure out about the interface for public interaction and I'm confused about creating a 2nd material class. I know my current one validates itself during instantiation, so I need another constructor to instantiate from the Query class, but I don't like to have 2 different classes for what seems the same object to me